# CSS Background Attachment Scroll/Fixed and Background Size cover

Tags: css, background-attachment

Why is `background-size:cover` different if `background-attachment: scroll` or `background-attachment: fixed` used?

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/enriqg9/Yn43U/

Comment: `background-attachment:fixed` seems to make the `background-size:cover` covering the whole page no matter which element the `background` is applied to. The element just becomes a small window helping us see a part of the large background-image. In fact the `background-attachment: scroll` makes the bg image scroll along the scrolling thumb of the page (not of the element), it's in fact fixed to the element. To make it scroll along the element, you can use `background-attachment:local` instead, but looks like we can't cover it over the element with `background-size:cover`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference isn't really in `background-size: cover`. The difference between `background-attachment: scroll` and `background-attachment: fixed` is that

"...**scroll** means that the background is fixed with regard to the element itself and does not scroll with its contents. (It is effectively attached to the element's border.)

"...**fixed** means that the background is fixed with regard to the viewport. Even if an element has a scrolling mechanism, a ‘fixed’ background doesn't move with the element."

as [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment) says. So you'll see in your fiddle that the `background-attachment: fixed` background doesn't remain in its containing element `<div id="two">` border. It is, instead taking on the fixed point of absolute positioning 0, 0 in the entire body's background.

In essence, `background-attachment: fixed` is overwriting `background-size: cover` and not allowing the latter style to take effect.

Comment: Thank you, I see here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3534441/how-to-fix-background-image-inside-div) that there is no work around with this besides changing the background position using js.

Answer (score 0):

When you assign `background-size:cover` to a `background-attachment: fixed` item its container will be the actual view port the item is sitting in. In your case the cat image is stretched to fit the total width of the fiddle result box. The reason why it is this way might be because since it applies position absolutely to the viewport it also gathers the size required from the viewport.