# Cover background with overflow scroll bar

Tags: html, css

I wish to cover the entire screen with an image.  Great, `background-size: cover;` comes to the rescue.  But then I want to include another element which has a fixed width with a scroll bar.  When doing so and making the screen smaller, the entire screen is no longer covered.  See https://output.jsbin.com/rogupezopu (screenshot and code duplicated below).  How do I cover the entire screen when utilizing a overflow scroll bar?

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Testing</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body,div {margin:0;padding:0;}

            #wrapper {
                height:840px;
                background-image:url(http://s24.postimg.org/781yqtfdh/background2.jpg);
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-size: cover;
                background-attachment: fixed;  /*http://stackoverflow.com/a/19364033/1032531 Doesn't work*/
                /* background-attachment: scroll; */  /*http://stackoverflow.com/a/23050520/1032531 Doesn't work*/
                /* background-size: 100% 100%; also doesn't work */
                /* background-position: center; probably redundent? */ 
            }
            #content {
                margin:0 auto;
                width: 960px;
                height:100%;
                overflow:auto;
            }
        </style> 
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="content">
                Ius ne quod posidonium, agam apeirian gubergren id eos, dolores percipit vis ex. Ex discere liberavisse his, sonet nominati conclusionemque et vis. Et admodum oporteat sit, eam facer affert mediocritatem ad, mea id omnium instructior. Pri ex natum option incorrupte, sit unum pertinax theophrastus ut.

                Nam an saperet delectus tractatos. Ad option persecuti appellantur usu. Dicta habemus fuisset per ea, ius adhuc iracundia ei. Te timeam integre pro, ex dolore possim audiam vis.

                Nam te tamquam omittam, eu diceret complectitur ius, quem omnesque sensibus in vel. Has eirmod accumsan atomorum ut, vel ei quod omittantur, expetendis neglegentur eu vim. Ad audiam fuisset cum. Quis mutat fabellas te nam, usu ut sumo suscipiantur, eos at lorem aeque graeci. In paulo disputationi ius, vide dissentias sadipscing eos cu.

                Usu te graece vivendo, ludus latine nonumes te has. Pri id quando tantas offendit, nam ea viderer dissentiet. Facilis consequat concludaturque sea ut, an mel persius evertitur eloquentiam. Facilisis repudiare conceptam sit an.
            </div>
        </div>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Works fine for me your demo.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Is there a special reason you want a horizontal scroll bar? Can you not just add "max-width: 100%" to the content div?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/RMBSnuN.png

Comment: @divy3993 You need to resize your window so its less than 960 wide and then scroll to the right.

Comment: @Michael  The content in `#content` is user provided via tinymce and will likely not collapse nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `#content` has a fixed width.

`#wrapper` has `width:100%` by default.

`#wrapper` will have the width of the screen.

So, the problem is that the `background-size:cover` is on the `#wrapper` and therefore will be limited to the screen width.

Solution? Move the background to the `#content` or increase the `#wrapper` width to a fixed value also with `min-width: 960px`.

Another solution would be limiting the size of the `#content` with `width: 100%; max-width: 960px;`

### Solution 1:

```css
body,
div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#wrapper {
  height: 840px;
  background-image: url(http://s24.postimg.org/781yqtfdh/background2.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
#content {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 960px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  #wrapper {
    background: none;
  }
  #content {
    background-image: url(http://s24.postimg.org/781yqtfdh/background2.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="content">
    Ius ne quod posidonium, agam apeirian gubergren id eos, dolores percipit vis ex. Ex discere liberavisse his, sonet nominati conclusionemque et vis. Et admodum oporteat sit, eam facer affert mediocritatem ad, mea id omnium instructior. Pri ex natum option
    incorrupte, sit unum pertinax theophrastus ut. Nam an saperet delectus tractatos. Ad option persecuti appellantur usu. Dicta habemus fuisset per ea, ius adhuc iracundia ei. Te timeam integre pro, ex dolore possim audiam vis. Nam te tamquam omittam,
    eu diceret complectitur ius, quem omnesque sensibus in vel. Has eirmod accumsan atomorum ut, vel ei quod omittantur, expetendis neglegentur eu vim. Ad audiam fuisset cum. Quis mutat fabellas te nam, usu ut sumo suscipiantur, eos at lorem aeque graeci.
    In paulo disputationi ius, vide dissentias sadipscing eos cu. Usu te graece vivendo, ludus latine nonumes te has. Pri id quando tantas offendit, nam ea viderer dissentiet. Facilis consequat concludaturque sea ut, an mel persius evertitur eloquentiam.
    Facilisis repudiare conceptam sit an.
  </div>
</div>
```

### Solution 2:

Using `min-width` in the `#wrapper`.

```css
body,
div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#wrapper {
  height: 840px;
  background-image: url(http://s24.postimg.org/781yqtfdh/background2.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  min-width: 960px;
}
#content {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 960px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="content">
    Ius ne quod posidonium, agam apeirian gubergren id eos, dolores percipit vis ex. Ex discere liberavisse his, sonet nominati conclusionemque et vis. Et admodum oporteat sit, eam facer affert mediocritatem ad, mea id omnium instructior. Pri ex natum option
    incorrupte, sit unum pertinax theophrastus ut. Nam an saperet delectus tractatos. Ad option persecuti appellantur usu. Dicta habemus fuisset per ea, ius adhuc iracundia ei. Te timeam integre pro, ex dolore possim audiam vis. Nam te tamquam omittam,
    eu diceret complectitur ius, quem omnesque sensibus in vel. Has eirmod accumsan atomorum ut, vel ei quod omittantur, expetendis neglegentur eu vim. Ad audiam fuisset cum. Quis mutat fabellas te nam, usu ut sumo suscipiantur, eos at lorem aeque graeci.
    In paulo disputationi ius, vide dissentias sadipscing eos cu. Usu te graece vivendo, ludus latine nonumes te has. Pri id quando tantas offendit, nam ea viderer dissentiet. Facilis consequat concludaturque sea ut, an mel persius evertitur eloquentiam.
    Facilisis repudiare conceptam sit an.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good explanation, but don't think it solves my problem.  `#content` needs a fixed width with a scroll bar if needed, so `max-width: 960px;`.  And when the window is full, I definitely don't want the oncovered white sidebars.

Comment: Much better!  Maybe just use `min-width` on `#wrapper` instead?  https://output.jsbin.com/gunatohepa/1

Comment: You can also do that. Thats what I meant by : "or increase the #wrapper width to a fixed value also."

Comment: I never used media queries before and need to learn, but will go with `min-width`.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @user1032531 added as a solution then.

Answer (score 1):

Add `overflow: auto;` to your `#wrapper` element.

Doing this, your wrapper will extend to its content, and will be the one that scrolls, not your document.

Comment: Actually it does, except you may not see it because of your fixed height. You first need to scroll to the bottom to see the horizontal scroll bar.